# Wordpress RewriteRule for custom script

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, qtranslate-x

I have a qTranslate plugin that redirects all my pages with prefix /lt/. For example:

> /page/ -> /lt/page/

I also have a custom PHP file that I want to reach in root folder /wp_import/check_mail.php

Now when I try to reach this file I get redirected to /lt/wp_import/check_mail.php

So I created a rule with:

```
add_rewrite_rule('/lt/wp_import/check_mail.php', '/wp_import/check_mail.php', 'top');
```

.htaccess generates this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/lt/wp_import/check_mail.php //wp_import/check_mail.php [QSA,L]
```

However, I still get 404 wordpress page and I can't reach my custom PHP file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache ignores the leading slashes in the `REQUEST_URI` to match with your rules in `.htaccess`, thus rules starts with `/` and without `RewriteBase` will match nothing.

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^lt/wp_import/check_mail.php wp_import/check_mail.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I just removed slashes from add_rewrite_rule('lt/wp_import/check_mail.php', 'wp_import/check_mail.php', 'top'); and it worked. Thank you